# How to reference fields in a join expression in an Adodb recordset?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MSAccess VBA

```
dim rst as adodb.recordset
set rst = new adodb.recordset
rst.open "select * from tblTran inner join tblTranEntry on tbltran.id=tblTranentry.tranid",currentproject.connection
```

I can referenct fields from tblTran using rst!id
How do I reference the fields from the joined table? rst!tbltranentry.tranid doesn't work

Comment: Same way. However, need to pull fields into SELECT clause first. `SELECT tblTran.*, tblTranentry.* FROM`